# After resize disk , can't ssh to GCP Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-storage

I can't ssh to my instance after resize disk . I search for information and see some issue like 
- The disk if full 
- The ip
I create a snapshot , and the snapshot only has size 8G , even my disk is 50Gb

My error get in serial 
https://pastebin.com/LwND02Bs

Answer (score 0):

Disk resize will take effect only after connecting and [extending](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions) it from OS.
If your disk is full you will not be able to connect and perform this step.

I would recommend you to take the original disk and attach it to another VM as a [secondary disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) (dont follow the steps for formatting as this will delete your data). Then you can free up some space. Once you have done this you can stop the new instance and start the original VM from its disk.

Then you should be able to ssh and continue with resizing the disk.